# MongoDB find query takes 15 minutes, fails, and then immediately succeeds

Tags: c#, mongodb

I'm using the C# Mongo Driver (v 2.11.2) in an ASP.NET Core 3 application running on Alpine in a Docker container.  I'm executing what looks like a very simple Find query:

```
var filter = Builders<PersonStream>.Filter.Eq(p => p.AlternateId, id); // id is a string
var stream = collection.Find<PersonStream>(filter).FirstOrDefault();
```

Most of the time this query executes just fine and very quickly.  Typically this query is not going to find any records in the collection (it's a pre-check to make sure someone with that ID doesn't have a record already).

However, every few executions of this query seem to hang.  The query will hang for about 15 minutes, fail, and then the driver appears to retry the query which then immediately succeeds.  Logging the events of the driver looks like this (logging the operation id, command JSON, and time to fail/succeed):

```
[02:15:17 DBG] START find [349]: { "find" : "people", "filter" : { "AlternateId" : "1186510" }, "limit" : 1, "$db" : "mydb", "lsid" : { "id" : CSUUID("08cfb4f6-84b2-4e5a-a961-1c796b5bd5b0") }, "$clusterTime" : { "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1601950250, 1), "signature" : { ... } } }
[02:30:56 ERR] FAILURE find [349]: 00:15:38.3976578
[02:30:56 DBG] START find [349]: { "find" : "people", "filter" : { "AlternateId" : "1186510" }, "limit" : 1, "$db" : "mydb", "lsid" : { "id" : CSUUID("08cfb4f6-84b2-4e5a-a961-1c796b5bd5b0") }, "$clusterTime" : { "clusterTime" : Timestamp(1601951445, 2), "signature" : { ... } } }
[02:30:56 DBG] SUCCESS 349: 00:00:00.0014953
```

I have an index on this AlternateId field, but it doesn't appear to influence this query.  Any idea what the source of this massive delay is?

Comment: What is the failure?

Comment: I am trying to log the exception, but there doesn't appear to be one (the exception in the failure event is null).

Comment: Check it on mongo side. Check open TCP connections on system level, check open connections in  mongo shell. check db.currentOp() when it hangs. Check if there is a pattern on the client side, like if it correlates with connection pool.